# Route issue: URL doesn't change

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

I've created a page to edit a message, I can edit my message and save in my database. After the save, I  `return View::make("messages.index");`

But if I look at the URL, it is: http://localhost:8000/update/42 instead of http://localhost:8000/messages

Did I do something wrong? (I assume I made a mistake in my routes.php, but I can't find it)

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => '/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
}));

Route::get("Messages", function()
{
    return View::make("Messages.index");
});

Route::resource('messages', 'MessageController');
Route::post('messages/{messages}', 'MessageController@destroy');
Route::put('update/{messages}', array('as' => 'putMessage', 'uses' => 'MessageController@update'));
Route::get('messages/{messages}/edit', array('as' => 'editMessage', 'uses' => 'MessageController@edit'));

Route::post('messages', array('as' => 'storeMessage', 'uses' => 'MessageController@store'));
```

MessageController:

```
<?php

class MessageController extends \BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::join('tblMessages_tblTeams', 'tblMessages.PK_message', '=', 'tblMessages_tblTeams.FK_message')
            ->join('tblTeams', 'tblMessages_tblTeams.FK_team', '=', 'tblTeams.PK_team')
            ->where('PK_team', 1)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();

        return View::make("messages.index")->withMessages($messages); 
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    // HARD CODED WILL BE REPLACED WHEN ABLE TO LOG IN
    // FK_user => Auth::id()->FK_team 
    public function store()
    {
        $date = new DateTime;

        // INSERT IN DATABASE
        $message = new Message;
        $message->FK_user = 1;
        $message->priority = Input::get("messagePriority");
        $message->title = Input::get('messageTitle');
        $message->content = Input::get('messageContent');
        $message->visible = true;
        $message->showFrom = Input::get('messageShowFrom');
        $message->removeFrom = Input::get('messageHideFrom');
        $message->created_at = $date;
        $message->updated_at = $date;
        $message->save();

        $message->teams()->attach(array(1,3));

        return Redirect::back();
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        $deleteMessage = Message::findOrFail($id); 
        $deleteMessage->visible = 0;
        $deleteMessage->save();

        return Redirect::back();
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $message = Message::findOrFail($id); 
        $showFrom = $message->showFrom;
        $removeFrom = $message->removeFrom;
        $showFrom = str_replace(' 00:00:00', '', $showFrom);
        $removeFrom = str_replace(' 00:00:00', '', $removeFrom);
        return View::make('messages.index')
            ->withMessage($message)
            ->with("showFrom", $showFrom)
            ->with("removeFrom", $removeFrom);
    }


    public function update($id)
    {   
        $date = new DateTime;
        $editMessage = Message::findOrFail($id); 

        $editMessage->FK_user = 1;
        $editMessage->priority = Input::get("messagePriority");
        $editMessage->title = Input::get('messageTitle');
        $editMessage->content = Input::get('messageContent');
        $editMessage->visible = true;
        $editMessage->showFrom = Input::get('messageShowFrom');
        $editMessage->removeFrom = Input::get('messageHideFrom');
        $editMessage->updated_at = $date;
        $editMessage->save();

        return View::make("messages.index");    
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        //   
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        dd('destroy');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way it works because your form has been submitted to `update/42`. 
You can return by redirecting like below to have the URL you want the user to be at.

`return Redirect::to('/Messages');`

and if you want to carry any values to that view you can use 
`->withInput();`

Also refer [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects) for more information

Answer (score 2):

What you are returning here, is the page /app/views/Messages/index.php

```
return View::make("Messages.index");
```

If you want to call another route, you should use:

```
Redirect::route('messages');
```